# Ctypes LPSTR function argument

Tags: ctypes

Hello i have a function like this

```
GetAllActivMessagestring(LPSTR pszStrMessages)
```

It returns in the parameter `pszStrMessages` the strings of active alarm.
The strings are organized in an array of 25 strings of 50 char(49+nullterminator)

How i can define the variable `pszStrMessages` and pass it to the function with `ctypes` and then read the return value?

Thanks and regards

Comment: `LPSTR` isn't an array.  Are the strings just 49char<null>49char<null>... repeated 25 times, so you need a 1250-char buffer?  Best to show exactly how you would call this API from C as an example, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, instead of text.value i have used text.raw and than split the line by b'\xoo' and get the value from the resulting list
Regards